# Recursive binary search on ArrayList

Tags: java, recursion

I'm trying to do a ***recursive*** *binary search* on an ArrayList but not sure what the issue with my code is. I have a text file with a bunch of integer numbers that look like this:

217
320
550
212
12
17
3560
2999
211

The problem is that when I input a number to search the ArrayList, it always says the element does not exist, but I know it does!

```
        public static int binarySearch(List<Integer> arr, Integer l, Integer r, Integer x)
        {
            if (r>=l)
            {
                Integer mid = l + (r - l)/2;

                // If the element is present at the middle itself
                if ((arr.size()/2) == x)
                    return mid;

                // If element is smaller than mid, then it can only
                // be present in left subarray
                if ((arr.size()/2) > x)
                    return binarySearch(arr, l, mid-1, x);

                // Else the element can only be present in right
                // subarray
                return binarySearch(arr, mid+1, r, x);
            }
            // We reach here when element is not present in array
            return -1;
        }   
    }
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated, new programmer here!

Comment: If you post code, you should generally add a tag for the language used. It can help others find the question and it also helps with the color formatting of the code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You calculate `mid`, and then use `arr.size() / 2`, instead...

Replace them with `arr.get(mid)`, something like this:

```
public static int binarySearch(final List<Integer> arr, final int l, final int r, final Integer x)
{
   if (r >= l)
   {
      final int mid = l + (r - l) / 2;

      // If the element is present at the middle itself
      if (x.equals(arr.get(mid)))
         return mid;

      // If element is smaller than mid, then it can only
      // be present in left subarray
      if (arr.get(mid) > x)
         return binarySearch(arr, l, mid - 1, x);

      // Else the element can only be present in right
      // subarray
      return binarySearch(arr, mid + 1, r, x);
   }
   // We reach here when element is not present in array
   return -1;
}
```

Comment: Thank you!! That was really helpful :D

Answer (score 2):

The part where you check if the element is present is wrong, don't do this:

```
arr.size()/2 == x
arr.size()/2 > x
```

Instead, do this:

```
arr.get(mid) == x
arr.get(mid) > x
```

Because you're supposed to access the element at the `mid` position, not checking if half the list's size equals `x`.

Answer (score 0):

Shouldn't you replace `arr.size()` with `arr[mid]` or something like that? Looks like you don't compare the value of an item, but rather the *array size* itself, which is constant and totally irrelevant.